# Inserting external CSS in Internet Explorer using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to load external CSS into Internet explorer using console. When I write the injection code, it says there is a Syntax error.

```
$(document.head).append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fahaduddin.com/css-new/mystyles.css">');
```

Comment: use `$('head')` instead of `$(document.head)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var element = document.createElement("link");
element.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
element.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
element.setAttribute("href", "external.css");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler and I'm pretty sure faster way of doing this...

```
var style_link = document.createElement('link');
style_link.ref = 'stylesheet';
style_link.href = 'http://fahaduddin.com/css-new/mystyles.css';
document.head.append(style_link);
```

Comment: It says object doesn't support property or method append.